# Why does DBContext Find method need to validate cache to detect changes that are still pending commit to DB?

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework, find

> Invocations to this method [DBContext.Find] by default will trigger a validation of the object cache in order to detect changes that are still pending commit to the database

[Performance Considerations for Entity Framework 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853)

I don't understand at all: why the Find method needs to detect changes that aren't committed to DB? Why this can be useful to it? What's the reason to make this method validate cache for those changes?

The Find method returns the cached copy of an entity - irrespectively of whether it is saved to DB or not. If this entity doesn't exist in the cache, then Find method performs a query against a database, gets this entity and attaches it to the cache, then returns it to the caller. Why does it need to detect whether the entity is already committed to DB or still isn't?

Please, explain it to newbie!

P.S. Excuse me my English, it's not my native language!

Upd. Find method invokes DetectChanges method to detect changes. If AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false, then DetectChanges isn't invoked. What's the difference (except decreasing of performance) between calling Find method when AutoDetectChangesEnabled is true or false? 
I've already found the difference when calling Add method, here it is: http://ilmatte.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/entity-framework-code-first-always-disable-autodetectchanges-when-importing-data/, — but I still can't understand what's the difference when calling Find?